# jQuery Does Not Recognize <input> ID

Tags: jquery, html

Okay, so I am creating a survey for a FAQ page, and my jQuery will not recognize an id in an input or label tag. Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rating').click(function() {
    $('.rating').removeClass('selected');
    ratingClick(this);
});
});

function ratingClick(that) {
        console.log(that.id);
            if (that.id == 'rating4' || that.id == 'rating5') {
                var $form = $('#questions');
                $form.submit(function(){
                $.post($(this).attr('connect.php'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
                $form.replacewith("VERY NICE");
            },'json');
            return false;
            });
                }
            else {
                $('#getMore').fadeIn();
                $(that).toggleClass('selected');
            }
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $form = $('#questions');
    $form.submit(function(){
    $.post($(this).attr('connect.php'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
        $form.replacewith("VERY NICE");
    },'json');
return false;
});
});
```

As you can see, I am trying to make the form be submitted if the person chooses a rating of 4 or 5. When I click 4 or 5, it brings up the #getMore div instead of submitting it to the server and replacing the form with "VERY NICE". Here is the HTML of the form:

```
<body>
    <div id = "form">
    <form id="questions" action="connect.php" method="post">
    <h2>How helpful is this article?</h2>
    <div class="ratings">
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="rating1" value="1"><label class="rating" for="rating1">Not at all helpful</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="rating2" value="2"><label class="rating" for="rating2">Not very helpful</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="rating3" value="3"><label class="rating" for="rating3">Somewhat helpful</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="rating4" value="4"><label class="rating" for="rating4">Very helpful</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Q1" id="rating5" value="5"><label class="rating" for="rating5">Extremely helpful</label>
    </div>
    <div id="getMore">
        <h2>Please tell us why you didn't find this article helpful:</h2>
            <input type='checkbox' name="Q2_1" value="1">Not related to my issue<br/>
            <input type='checkbox' name="Q2_2" value="1">Too complicated explanations<br/>
            <input type='checkbox' name="Q2_3" value="1">Too much information<br/>
            <input type='checkbox' name="Q2_4" value="1">Incorrect information<br/>
            <input type='checkbox' name="Q2_5" value="1">Unclear information<br/>
            <input type='checkbox' name="Q2_6" value="1">Incomplete information<br/>
            <h2>Do you have any other feedback about this article?</h2>
            <p><input type="text" name="Q3" /><p>
        <div id = "submit"><input type='submit' value="Submit" /></div>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I target one of these radio buttons with an id or is there another way to do it without using id?

**EDIT: JFIDDLE LINK http://jsfiddle.net/amccoy022/uN7zv/**

Comment: Providing a working JSFiddle or similar is an excellent way to get answers and effective help, particularly when you've got potentially complex interactions between JS and HTML.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/amccoy022/uN7zv/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in the way you use this key word:

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rating').click(function() {
    $('.rating').removeClass('selected');
    ratingClick($(this));
});
});

function ratingClick(that) {
        console.log(that.prev('input').attr('id'));

var id = that.prev('input').attr('id');

if (id  == 'rating4' || id  == 'rating5') {


// code
}
```

**Edit**

Aditional Suggestion for your ok message if rating is 4 or 5 :

Don't replace the form . Just hide it and put your response message in a span our other html element.

Something like this:

```
function ratingClick(that) {
       console.log(that.prev('input').attr('id'));
         var info = $("#myinfo");
          var id = that.prev('input').attr('id');

            if (id  == 'rating4' || id == 'rating5') {
                var $form = $('#questions');
                $form.submit(function(){
                $.post($(this).attr('connect.php'), $(this).serialize(), function(response){
                form.hide();
                //$form.replacewith("VERY NICE");
                 info.html(response); // if you now how the response message is
                // or info.html("ok message");
            },'json');
            return false;
            });
                }
            else {
                $('#getMore').fadeIn();
                $(that).toggleClass('selected');
            }
    }
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Now I need to figure out how to submit the form when rating 4 or 5 are selected and replace the form with a "thank you" message :)

Comment: @Alex Please mark the question as answered if this answer helped solve your problem :) I edited my answer with a suggestion to your ok message

Answer (score 0):

Your `class="rating"` is on the label tag, but your ratingClick function looks like it assumes it is passed the `<input>` tag.  That is a problem.

If you want the click handler on the label, the move the `class="rating"` to the relevant `<input>` tags.

---

Also, in this code:

```
$('.rating').click(function() {
    $('.rating').removeClass('selected');
    ratingClick(this);
});
```

You are removing the `selected` class from all `.rating` elements.  If you want to just remove it from the clicked element, then do it like this:

```
$('.rating').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    ratingClick(this);
});
```

---

If you want the click handler on the input tags, you can change your click handler to this:

```
$('.ratings input').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    ratingClick(this);
});
```

Comment: I can't move the class="rating" to the input tags because that removes the styling from the button, is there a better way to do this so I do not lose my styling? Also - that jQuery does what I want it to (it makes the styled boxes act as radio buttons). Here is a jfiddle link to show you what it looks like (make sure to enable jquery on the left side): http://jsfiddle.net/amccoy022/uN7zv/

Comment: @Alex - add a new class (that has nothing to do with styling) to your `<input>` tags and trigger the click handler with that class.  Or use `$('.ratings input').click(function() { ...})`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the `<label>` object to the ratingClick function.  As such there is no "id" attribute.  However, you do have the "for" attribute and you can get the ID from this attribute.

```
        function ratingClick(that) {
            console.log($(that).attr('for'));
            if ($(that).attr('for') == 'rating4' || $(that).attr('for') == 'rating5') {
                //Code
            } else {
                //Code
            }
        }
```

And I know this is probably just an example, but I would suggest you add `<label>` items to your check boxes in the "getMore" div.  It's just a personal gripe when I can't click on the label to select a check box.